# C# - Partition List of Objects into varying size partitions

Tags: c#, .net, cluster-analysis

I have a very large list of objects (a class I have defined myself). I need to partition this list into many different partitions of varying size. A partition could even contain just one object. Basically I am trying to cluster this list based off of the amount of similarity between these objects.

Here is an example of my code looks like:

```
    class Bar
    {
        public List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();

        // pseudocode of goal
        List<List<Foo>> partitionedlist = new List<List<Foo>>();

        List<Foo> partition1 = Partition(fooList.SelectMany(item.inputs.intersect(item2.inputs)));
    }
    class Foo
    {
        public List<String> inputs = new List<string>();
    }
```

They need to be partitioned according to the amount (percentage) of matches that the objects have in their 'inputs' list. I would like to be able to potentially limit the size of partitions as well.

Comment: I've read it and I'm a little confused so apologies... Can you clarify it any?

Comment: A regular `GroupBy` should be able to handle this.

Comment: No problem, I am being intentionally vague so I expect some confusion. I want to make smaller lists of objects from one larger one, and I want these partitions to be created based on the similarity between the property of Foo that I have shown above. Does this help at all?

Comment: You need to clarify your partitioning criteria .. for example, if `inputs` has 10 items and 4 of them are equal.. does it have more or less _matches_ than another `inputs` with 10 items and 2 pairs of equal strings ?

Comment: First, will there be a partition for each object, such that foreach base object in base list you get a list of objects that are x% similar to base object?  If not, what is your comparison baseline?  Do you want each partition to be a bucket of objects that are between x% and y% similar to the baseline?  Start by actually defining how you want to partition.   Then, you will also need to custom define your "intersect" method, probably in a manner that returns a % similarity as the result.

Comment: Ahmad, prior to doing any partitioning, I calculate an average for similarity across the entire List<Foo>, and this becomes my threshold for similarity. This may not be the proper way to do it, but I will have a better idea later on. For instance, the average may be like 30% similarity across the entire list. So, I would then want to partition this list based on a >= 30% similarity between `inputs` for respective elements in the original list.

Comment: @user7396598 The "intersect" method is just to get a count for the number of shared values in `inputs` which will be expressed as a percentage given the size of both lists in each object. Ideally I would like to partition into buckets of objects that all share common values in their `inputs` lists.

Comment: So you're equally weighting each input, so a count divided by total will give you % similarity.  That's an easy intersect function.  "...that all share common values in their inputs lists."  100% share?  50%+ share?  If not 100% then you'll still need one partition for each base object because "a" match 50% "b" and 50% "c" does not require "b" match 50% "c".  Defining your rules for partitioning starts becoming complex, the code to then make it happen will be even more so...

Comment: @user7396598 The % share depends on what I calculate as the average across the entire list. Yes, the code I already have to do so is fairly complex and I don't have a lot of control over how it clusters. That is what I am trying to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an efficient way to use LINQ to do this, but you can loop through all the `Foo`s and create buckets based on how similar each `Foo` is to the contents of the buckets, and create a new bucket when the similarity is too low. I used the average of each `Foo` with all the `Foo`s in a bucket as the similarity between a single `Foo` and a bucket (`List<Foo>`) and found the bucket with the highest similarity.

Assuming a function for computing the similarity between two `Foo`s (I used the number of common `inputs` members divided by the max count of `inputs`) you put them in buckets:

```
class Bar {
    public List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
    public List<List<Foo>> partitionedFoos;

    public void PartitionFoos() {
        partitionedFoos = Foo.PartitionFoos(fooList);
    }
}

class Foo {
    public List<String> inputs = new List<string>();

    public double Similarity(Foo anotherFoo) {
        return inputs.Intersect(anotherFoo.inputs).Count()/(double)(inputs.Count+anotherFoo.inputs.Count);
    }

    public static List<List<Foo>> PartitionFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
        var answers = new List<List<Foo>>();
        answers.Add(new List<Foo>());
        var fooe = foos.GetEnumerator();
        if (fooe.MoveNext()) {
            answers[0].Add(fooe.Current);
            while (fooe.MoveNext()) {
                var curFoo = fooe.Current;
                var max = answers.Select((lf, i) => (AvgSimilarity: lf.Average(f => f.Similarity(curFoo)), i)).MaxBy(si => si.AvgSimilarity);
                if (max.AvgSimilarity < 0.4) // time for a new bucket!
                    answers.Add(new List<Foo> { curFoo });
                else
                    answers[max.i].Add(curFoo);
            }
        }
        return answers;
    }
}
```

PS I used an extension method I have defined for finding the max:

```
public static T MaxBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> key, Comparer<TKey> keyComparer) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => keyComparer.Compare(key(a), key(b)) > 0 ? a : b);
public static T MaxBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> key) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(key(a), key(b)) > 0 ? a : b);
public static T MinBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> key, Comparer<TKey> keyComparer) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => keyComparer.Compare(key(a), key(b)) < 0 ? a : b);
public static T MinBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> key) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(key(a), key(b)) < 0 ? a : b);
```

Comment: I went ahead and implemented this. I of course had to make some changes for it to fit my needs. The grouping here is perfect for my use case, thank you so much! Would it be possible to do this in a way where I could more evenly distribute the sizes of the buckets?

Comment: To be more specific, I perform some operations on the buckets of these objects after partitioning. Then they are used to generate certain files. The results that I obtain using these files can be skewed in an undesirable way if certain buckets have a significantly higher quantity than most others. I'm playing around with the idea currently.

Comment: Nevermind, stupid question. I believe I've figured it out. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: @Chippy Yeah, I think answering your question would require much more detail about the nature of your data and problem if you want to retain grouping by similarity, such as distribution of similarity. Obviously perverse cases of data could create single groupings no matter what arbitrary bucket rule was used, so you would have to adjust the rule based on the data.